# I cannot center my button and don't know why

Tags: html, css, button, center

I tried to put a button in the center of my div but I couldn't though all my other contents are centered.

**My code:**

```css
.middle {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

.middle section {
  padding: 18vh 6%;
  line-height: 0.5;
  color: #EE6352;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: calc(16px + 3vw);
}

.middle ul {
  text-align: left;
}

.middle li {
  font-size: calc(12px + 2vw);
  line-height: 1.25;
  color: #2A2D34;
}

.middle p {
  font-size: calc(14px + 2.4vw);
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #2A2D34;
}

.upbutton {
  padding: 10px;
  background: #1ac6ff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-style: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  transition: background 0.3s;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px rgba(102, 102, 102, 0.5);
}

.upbutton img {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
}

.upbutton:hover {
  background: #00ace6;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.94);
  -ms-transform: scale(0.94);
  transform: scale(0.94);
}

.upbutton:active {
  background: #0086b3;
}
```

```html
<a id="middle">
  <div class="middle">
</a>
<section>
  <a href="#top"><button class="upbutton"><img src="img/arrow.png"></button></a>
  <h1>content</h1>
  <ul>
    <li>content</li>
    <li>content</li>
    <li>content</li>
  </ul>
  <p>...and more</p>
</section>
</div>
```

I also searched on this problem and tried to put this into the .upbutton class:

```
margin:0;
-ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
transform: translateX(-50%);
```

and it centered my button. But when I hover, it didn't center anymore.

I don't know why I'm kinda new to this. Can anyone explain and help me, tks a lot!

Comment: Your HTML is wrong. <div class="middle"> starts inside <a> so it should close inside that </div>. If there is a typing mistake, fix that and update the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember to add a transform: translateX(-50%); on the :hover selector for the button, this way it wont go back. If you change the transform property on hover it overides the existing one, so it goes back to translateX(0)

```css
    .upbutton:hover {
  background: #00ace6;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) scale(0.94);
  -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) scale(0.94);
  transform: translateX(-50%) scale(0.94);
}
```

Comment: I thought i just need to put the translateX(-50%) into the hover, not the transform so it didn't work :(. Btw, thanks a lot :D

Answer (score 0):

```html
<head>
    <style>
        .middle
        {
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        text-align: center;
        position: relative;
        }
        .middle section
        {
          padding: 18vh 6%;
          line-height: 0.5;
          color: #EE6352;
          font-weight: 400;
          font-size:calc(16px + 3vw);

        }
        .middle ul
        {
          text-align: left;
        }
        .middle li
        {
          font-size: calc(12px + 2vw);
          line-height: 1.25;
          color: #2A2D34;
        }
        .middle p
        {
          font-size: calc(14px + 2.4vw);
          font-weight: 400;
          color: #2A2D34;
        }
        .upbutton
        {
          padding: 10px;
          background: #1ac6ff;
          border-radius: 50%;
          border-style: none;
          cursor: pointer;
          position: absolute;
          top:50%;
          left:50%;
          transition: background 0.3s;
          box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px rgba(102, 102, 102, 0.5);
        }
        .upbutton img{width: 25px;height: 25px;}
        .upbutton:hover{ background: #00ace6;
          -webkit-transform: scale(0.94);
                -ms-transform: scale(0.94);
                transform: scale(0.94); }
        .upbutton:active{background: #0086b3;}
    </style>
    </head>
    <a id="middle"><div class="middle"></a>
          <section>
          <a href="#top"><button class="upbutton"><img src="https://png.pngtree.com/png-vector/20190419/ourmid/pngtree-vector-up-arrow-icon-png-image_956434.jpg"></button></a>
          <h1>content</h1>
          <ul>
          <li>content</li>
          <li>content</li>
          <li>content</li>
          </ul>
          <p>...and more</p>
          </section>
          </div>
```

In this example you can just use `'position': absolute` and `top:50%,left:50%`

Comment: i tried to put the 'left: 50%' because i want it on top, but it's doesn't change anything, you can run code snippet and see or you can see here:  https://imgur.com/a/MT4Ri85

Answer (score 0):

Try doing it directly in the HTML. EDIT: Try using JS.

```html
<center><button onclick = "goToTop()" id = "buttonId"><img src="img/arrow.png"></img></button></center>
<script>
function goToTop(){
var currentLink = window.location.href;
window.location = currentLink+'#top';
}
</script>
```

Tell me if this doesn't work for you and I'll try to fix it. Also, please accept if this did work for you. It works for me in Chrome.

Comment: Thanks for helping me, but it still doesn't work :(

Comment: Wait - I just realized why it didn't work. I just updated my snippet @tomdapchai

Comment: Hmm, i don't think that <img> has closing tag @omsrisaissrnamaha.

Comment: Okay @tomdapchai I've updated once again. Tell me if it works. It worked for me.

Comment: Do you think you could accept my answer @tomdapchai if it worked? It would mean A LOT to me. Thank you!

Comment: i really want to do that, but i can only accept one answer due to the rule.

Comment: Btw, when i have enough reputation, i will upvote for you :D. I greatly appreciated that you trying to help me!

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to center it just add

> top: 50%; property to the .upbutton class

[image]

Comment: it still doesn't work, but thanks for help :(

Comment: you can see in the picture that you uploaded that the button didn't center

Comment: i think you need to center it's parent first in order to center it in the exact middle of your page! check the parent css.

Comment: draw on the picture where do you want to center it exactly